# How should I insulate my shed to avoid mold and mildew?

Tags: insulation, moisture, humidity, workshop

I'm having a 16 by 12' shed built on-site because of difficulties getting down my driveway. It's to be a woodworking shop to build small furniture in.

I live in Beaufort SC. It will have cement lap board siding on top of the sheathing with 2 by 4 studs. The roof will be shingles on top of the felt paper, with a ridge vent.

The question is how to insulate the inside walls to prevent mold  or mildew.

Comment: Fight off mold & mildew where? In the walls? In the shop?

Comment: between the outside walls and insulation

Answer (score 1):

I think the key thing is to use a quality house wrap made for the concrete/fiber lap siding. Concrete fiber siding will transfer moisture much more readily then wood, vinyl, etc. Products like DuPont DrainWrap (essentially their standard house wrap thats corrugated) will allow for air movement and water drainage. There are a lot of other products that employ similar techniques but the key is to make sure there's breathing room between the siding and sheathing.

Also, the wrap should be stapled using caps and taped per the manufactures specs.

For the roof I would look to high performance sythentic underlayments and ensure you have adaquare venting in your eaves